# how to assign color to helperText material ui to highlight error in TextField

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

How to assign a color to `helperText` **material-UI** to highlight the error in `TextField`.I am unable to set the color to `helperText` in material-UI.

I tried to use `MuiFormHelperText-root-406` to apply CSS 
but it does not work

```
<Grid item xs={3}>
   <TextField
       label="EmailId" 
       name="emailId" 
       value={editItem.emailId} 
       onChange={this.editInputValue} 
       helperText={this.state.emailerror}  />      
</Grid>


.MuiFormHelperText-root-406{
   color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
 }
```

Comment: Which version of Material UI are you using? (you can check in your node module folder @material-ui\system\CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 3):

Add this code: add `className={classes.textField}` in `TextField`

```
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 200,
    '& p':{
      color:'blue',
    },
  },
```

```
      <TextField
        id="standard-helperText"
        label="Helper text"
        defaultValue="Default Value"
        className={classes.textField}
        helperText="Some important text"
        margin="normal"
      />
```

Comment: You try this.. @Prathamesh Shirshivkar

Comment: I tried css in const styles but only supported for react functions.I want style to helpertext inside react component

Comment: can u share the screen shot of what u want? @PrathameshShirshivkar

Answer (score 1):

@arpita-patel's answer is correct but you should know that you can also just add this to your CSS:

```
.MuiFormHelperText-root {
    color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Or do it based on the parent:

```
.MuiTextField-root p {
    color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Each of the above worked for me. I am using Material UI 4.0.2

Comment: I tried the above thing.Still not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which version of Material UI are you using? (you can check in your node module folder @material-ui\system\CHANGELOG.md)

Answer (score 1):

The best way which I found to style the `helperText` for the TextField component is similar to the way presented by Arpita Patel.
The only difference is that I am using the attribute `classes` instead of `className` as it has been described in [Material-UI docs here](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)

You can find there that `TextField` component can use only one CSS rule name called `root` (global class is called `.MuiTextField-root`).

So basically you need to use the below code to style `helperText` as you like:

**JSX (based on your initial code example)**

```
const classes = useStyles();

<TextField
  label="EmailId" 
  name="emailId" 
  value={editItem.emailId} 
  onChange={this.editInputValue} 
  helperText={this.state.emailerror}
  classes={{root: classes.textField}}
/>
```

**STYLE via makeStyles**

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  textField: {
    '& p':{
      /* your style for helperText here*/
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it can be done easier:

Simple add prop sx to TextField component

```
sx={ "& p": { //styles for your helper text } }
```

Answer (score -2):

If @ange-loron's answer didn't work, try to add `!important` :

```
.MuiFormHelperText-root {
    color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5) !important;
}
```